# How to get automated data about a stock symbol?

Tags: stocks, historical-data, online-data-source

I'm running a small stock-analysis program on my local machine.
To do the analysis over a large amount of historical stock charts, I pull
the data form [Alphavantage's](https://www.alphavantage.co/) API using the curl command below.

Given the ticker-symbol of an equity (in this case `GBLIL`), I grab its data like this:

```
$ curl \
--request GET \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=GBLIL&apikey=MY-API-KEY&outputsize=compact"

{    
    "Meta Data": {        
        "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",        
        "2. Symbol": "GBLIL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-05-18",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },    
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-05-18": {
            "1. open": "25.4200",
            "2. high": "25.6600",
            "3. low": "25.4200",
            "4. close": "25.6600",
            "5. adjusted close": "25.6600",
            "6. volume": "11875",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },.......
```

But I would like to know what kind of equity GBLIL is.
Is it a stock? Is it an Exchange Traded Fund? Is it a Bond?

Where/How can I get this information from an automated and free source? I need an API that my program can hit hundreds of times per minute via HTTP request. Not a webpage that I manually type a stock ticker into and see the result.

Comment: Asking for product/service recommendations is off-topic here. That said, this valuable data is not likely to be free for hitting hundreds of times per minute.

Comment: Getting actual stock quotes hundreds of times per minute via API is free from Alphavantage.com. So I figure just finding out what type of equity a symbol is should be much lower-hanging (and free) fruit

Comment: That's interesting that it's free, hadn't heard of them before. The bummer about many of them is that once they become popular they lose interest in providing a free service.

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend.  Type the symbol in the search box and Voila! , information is readily available.

A superb source for information on income securities is QuantumOnline.  Here's the link to GLBIL:

http://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm

You may have to sign up to access some of the content but membership is free.

Comment: I need it in a way that can be automated. 

So I need an API that my program can hit hundreds of times per minute via HTTP request. Not a webpage that I manually type a stock ticker into and see the result. Sorry I didn't explain that more clearly in my original question. Editing now.

Comment: I answered "What kind of equity GBLIL is? Is it a stock? Is it an Exchange Traded Fund? Is it a Bond?"  I can't help you with the API stuff.